# How can i detect LINE app call state in my app?

Tags: java, android

I am a beginner to android.I have an app and i am using LINE app for my application.So after invoking LINE app from my app,when i make a LINE call and get disconnected after the call , i want to return to my application.Is there any way to do that?

Comment: could you show us the code you have tried pls? and maybe a website reference url to the docs of Line?

Comment: I don't think you can control other app's navigation. It depends on the LINE app if they open another activity/screen or finish the current screen so that that you can return to the originating screen (which is your app).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49302694/how-do-i-detect-skype-telegram-whatsapp-calls-when-my-messenger-app-is-in-a-call @Blundell

Comment: is there any way to detect its call state??? @SomeshKumar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Documentation for Notification Listner](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html). this might come in handy. and [try this sample](https://github.com/kpbird/NotificationListenerService-Example/) from *kpbird*. see whether you are getting any sign of call state. most probably even you dont see a notification in the notification panel, there can be few. just like ***true caller*** app detects and reads caller information. 
and dont forget to update your manifest. and you need to give permission to read notifications too.

```
<service android:name=".NotificationListener"
     android:label="@string/service_name"
     android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE">
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService" />
</intent-filter>
```

cheers!